# Twitter Card Preview doesn't fetch my image

Tags: html, twitter, apache2, meta-tags

I'm using the [Twitter Card Preview](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/preview) tool to test my Twitter Card set up.

```
<meta property="twitter:url" content="http://liberalgeek.com/content/why-do-atheists-celebrate-christmas" />
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta property="twitter:description" content="I can&#039;t speak for all atheists, I can only speak for myself, so please leave a comment below and explain why you celebrate Christmas! When I hear someone ask, &quot;Why do atheists celebrate Christmas?&quot; my first thought often is: Better Question: Why do Christians celebrate Christmas?" />
<meta property="twitter:creator" content="@kennywyland" />
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Why do Atheists celebrate Christmas?" />
```

When I use the above meta tags, the Preview works and I get the expected results. When I try to add a twitter:image tag though, it fails. Here is an example:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://liberalgeek.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Christmas%20Tree.jpg" />
```

If I include a twitter:image meta tag and I click the Preview button, it spins for a bit and then gives me the error:

```
Looks like something is technically wrong.
Please try again in a few minutes.
```

I've tried other images on that site with no success. I've tried other (non-drupal) sites hosted on the same apache server to make sure it wasn't a drupal problem:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://www.journalscape.com/kenny/images/acupuncture-kenny-2003-08-20-small.jpg" />
```

If I copy one of these images to a different machine with a different apache server, twitter sees it and it works just fine. Twitter shows it in the preview.

I have checked my robots.txt on both sites. Nothing in my robots.txt should prevent Twitterbot from fetching, but just in case I've explicitly added the code they suggested:

```
User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow:
```

However, I am watching my apache web logs scroll by and Twitter never attempts to fetch the image. When I click the preview button, I would expect to see an entry in the access log showing twitter fetching the image... but nothing. I've tried several images to make sure it wasn't an issue of caching.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I found one of the sites running on my machine (same apache) works just fine. If I use this image:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://www.geekqi.com/images/StylizedYinYangRedLucida.png" />
```

Then twitter fetches it immediately. I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: I just had a try and it was fine. I had a similar issue late last year where just one image was breaking for me and never worked out why (after a couple of days it just started working) so maybe a cache issue or something obscured behind the card mechanics

Comment: actually, it is twitter:image:src

Comment: As it turned out, the problem was a timing one. After adding the robots.txt file, I needed to wait a couple of hours for Twitter to see the new robots.txt and then it started fetching my images just fine.

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out, the problem was a timing one. After adding the robots.txt file, I needed to wait a couple of hours for Twitter to see the new robots.txt and then it started fetching my images just fine.